# Get custom catalog attribute in custom page

Tags: attributes

Hi in my custom page template i need display attribute catalog, I programmatically create attribute:

```
<?php require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID));
$installer = new Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup;
$attribute_second    = array(
    'group'         => 'Brands',
    'input'         => 'textarea',
    'type'          => 'varchar',
    'label'         => 'Brands',
    'backend'       => '',
    'visible'       => true,
    'required'      => false,
    'visible_on_front' => true,
    'global'        => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
);

$installer->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'brand_text_value', $attribute_second);
$installer->endSetup();?>
```

and then in catalog added tab Brands with textarea field, now need get value in custom page template, can you help, how i can get value in custom page.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I understood you correctly, but you could try smth like:

In case of getting *default value*:

```
$attributeCode = 'brand_text_value';
$eavConfig = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config');
$attribute = $eavConfig->getAttribute('catalog_product', $attributeCode);
```

*form value for certain product:*

```
$attributeCode = 'brand_text_value';
$attributeValue = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->load($_product->getId())
            ->getAttributeText($attributeCode);
```